# cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, types

In the following lines of code, lines 1,2,3 and 4 have essentially the same error:
View, EditText, Intent and TextView cannot be resolved to a type. I used the code on the developer.android.com site creating an Android Project under Building a Simple User Interface. How do I fix these errors?

```
 1   public void sendMessage(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
 2   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
 3   Intent intent = getIntent();
     String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 4   TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

Comment: do you have any errors in your xml files? that might prevent R.java from generating

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the dependencies. If you're using Eclipse press **Ctrl+Shift+O**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following `import`s:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! These took care of most errors. I have only 1 error left: